# How save documents in spring boot rest jpa postgresql

Tags: javascript, java, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I am working on project where user uploads files using rest endpoints.

Technology stack is : Java, SpringBoot, Rest, Jpa, Jpa-hibernate, postgesql.

I got some tutorials like http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-with-spring-mvc-and-hibernate

My requirement is different, endpoint is accepting only model object, like below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public VendorEntity update(@RequestBody @Valid VendorEntity entity) throws Exception {
    return vendorService.update(entity);
}
```

and `VendorEntity` is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vendor")
public class VendorEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<ContractEntity> contracts;
}
```

where as Contract entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contract")
public class ContractEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Lob
  @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
  private byte[] contract;
}
```

The FE is, (I don't know anything about this, i am not FE, actually i don't understand what it does)

```
  editContract( { contractIndex, file } ) {
    const vendor = Object.assign( {}, this.vendor );
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append( 'file', file );
    vendor.contracts[contractIndex].document = data; // this.getContractBase64(vendor, file, contractIndex );
    vendor.contracts[contractIndex].documentName = file.name;
    this.setState( { vendor } );
  }

getContractBase64( vendor, value, index ) {
    console.log(vendor);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(index);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL( value );
    const scope = this;
    reader.onload = function load () {
      vendor.contracts[index] = reader.result; // .substring( 22, reader.result.length );
    };
    reader.onloadend = function loadend() {
      scope.setState( { vendor } );
    };
    this.setState( { vendor } );
  }
```

The error when i upload,

I get logs in eclispe:

```
33m WARN 24898 --- [nio-8092-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of byte[] out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@cec05da; line: 1, column: 2068] (through reference chain: com.core.vendor.domain.VendorEntity["contracts"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.core.vendor.domain.ContractEntity["document"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of byte[] out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@cec05da; line: 1, column: 2068] (through reference chain: com.core.vendor.domain.VendorEntity["contracts"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.core.vendor.domain.ContractEntity["document"])
```

and at front end:

```
fail @ vendor.store.jsx:252
(anonymous) @ AltStore.js:88
(anonymous) @ AltStore.js:87
handleDispatch @ AltStore.js:54
(anonymous) @ AltStore.js:86
_invokeCallback @ Dispatcher.js:198
dispatch @ Dispatcher.js:174
(anonymous) @ index.js:83
Alt.batchingFunction @ index.js:51
dispatch @ index.js:66
dispatch @ index.js:31
action @ index.js:49
fire @ StoreMixin.js:91
(anonymous) @ StoreMixin.js:100
:8001/#/vendors/1?_k=p3zae4:1 Uncaught (in promise) Object {data: Object, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Object, config: Object…}



   data: Object
error:"Bad Request"
exception:"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"
message:"Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of byte[] out of START_OBJECT token↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@cec05da; line: 1, column: 2068] (through reference chain: com.core.vendor.domain.VendorEntity["contracts"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.core.vendor.domain.ContractEntity["document"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of byte[] out of START_OBJECT token↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@cec05da; line: 1, column: 2068] (through reference chain: com.core.vendor.domain.VendorEntity["contracts"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.core.vendor.domain.ContractEntity["document"])"
path:"/vendor/1"
status:400
timestamp:1502447177798
```

Comment: did you try to implement serializable in your entity class ??

Comment: you mean, `ContractEntity implements Serializable` ?? Yes, same error.

Comment: @scott please show a request body which you're actually sending